# Does VS-2013 main window get saved?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide, save, preferences

Every time I launch Visual Studio 2013, the main window pops up with the default width, height, and position on my screen. This forces me to resize and move it the the way I want every time.

Did I miss an option somewhere to make the window retain its settings from the last time I closed it?

Comment: Yes it is saved when you exit VS.  To C:\Users\YourName\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Settings\CurrentSettings.vssettings.  You'll need to find out what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I use Windows 7 and I realized it does save the window if I move it normally or if I drag it to the top of my screen to enlarge it to fullscreen.

However, if I drag it to the left or right border of the screen so that it automatically resizes itself to take half my screen, it won't save that at all for the next startup, so I have to manually resize it and move it to the border of the screen I want for it to save.

That's quite annoying since I usually work with 2 windows that take half my screen each and I often change their position with the drag-to-a-border feature from windows 7.

Comment: That's Aero Snap at work.  Yes, it is troublesome, it doesn't generate any notifications for a program.  Programmers need two monitors.

Comment: @Hans Passant I believe you are wrong, i've been programming AS3 using Flashdevelop for a very long time and it always saved the window position, even when I used "Aero Snap". It is clearly an issue on VS end.